# Need to Format String Date in different format in java

Tags: java, string, date, parseexception, dateformatter

I have a String date "30 Aug 2019". I want to format in "2019-08-30'. 
I am trying with following code. It is not working.

String input = "30 Aug 2019";
           Date date = sdf.parse(input);

```
       // Date to String:
      String strDate = sdf.format(date);
      System.out.println(strDate);
```

I am getting an error as 
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "30 Aug 2019"

Please help me, how to go ahead ?

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Best way to go ahead would be [to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and post it in your question. With the information you have posted this far, we cannot tell what’s wrong and thus cannot guide you. The exception you are mentioning doesn’t come from the piece of code you have posted.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

You are using terrible date-time classes that were outmoded years ago by the adoption of JSR 310. Use `java.time.LocalDate` instead.

And you neglected to specify a formatting pattern to match your input string. We do so here using the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class.

```
LocalDate
.parse(
    "30 Aug 2019" ,
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "d MMM uuuu" ).withLocale( Locale.US )
)
.toString()
```

> 2019-08-30

## *java.time*

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

Specify a `Locale` on your `DateTimeFormatter` to determine the human language and cultural norms needed for translating name of month, and such.

```
String input = "30 Aug 2019" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "d MMM uuuu" ).withLocale( Locale.US ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/eZ6rDW).

> ld.toString(): 2019-08-30

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Although you should use `java.time` classes, to answer your question, you need 2 SimpleDateFormats; one for parsing and one for formatting:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfIn = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat sdfOut = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

Date date = sdfIn.parse("30 Aug 2019");
String strDate = sdfOut.format(date);

System.out.println(strDate); // 2019-08-30
```